# iOS build number in Cordova app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Using Cordova 3.5.0, when I run `cordova prepare ios` it overwrites my build number as well as the app's version number, using the version string from `config.xml`.

From:

```
<widget id="tld.domain.app" version="1.0.1"
```

It sets the **CFBundleVersion** the same as the short version:

[image]

So I have to keep manually keep resetting my build number to my format which is `YYYYMMDD`.

Ideally I'd like it to either leave the build number alone, or be able to set it explicitly in the **config.xml** file.

Are either of these possible?

Comment: (I have tried adding a `build=N` attribute)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found the answer in [this resolved issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5093).

There are separate `versionCode` attributes (separate to `version`) for iOS and Android, that need to be added to your config.xml file:

```
<widget ... android-versionCode="201406092" ios-CFBundleVersion="201406092"
```

Comment: A couple of weeks after this answer was posted, this information was [added](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/commit/1d07d1d38fa485d7d308a7ecbe753ff119ac52f5) to the [docs for the `config.xml` file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html) ("Additional Versioning" section).

Comment: Heads up, I noticed that in a new(er) cordova config.xml it's using `version="1.23.456"` and that number shows up for me on both Android & iOS builds.

Answer (score 32):

This post [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/automatic-build-numbering/9283/8) was a little clearer to me, a little more complete, so I mention it just in case it helps.  Note that, effectively, it is almost the exact same as what Ade said.  I only provide it because the first time I read Ade's answer, I was confused and did not fully understand his answer until I saw the answer below.

> If you want to separate the build number from the version number, you
>   can add the following attributes to the `widget` tag in your config.xml:
>
> ```
> version="VERSIONNR" android-versionCode="BUILDNR" ios-CFBundleVersion="BUILDNR"
> ```
>
> so the complete tag, with those attributes included, looks something like this:
>
> ```
> <widget id="APPID" version="VERSIONNR" android-versionCode="BUILDNR" 
> ios-CFBundleVersion="BUILDNR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
> xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
> ```
>
> (text in uppercase are placeholders)

Comment: Have to be careful with the `android-versionCode` attribute, I think it can't accept the same values as the `ios-CFBundleVersion` attribute. I had problems opening a cordova app in AndroidStudio when I set those attributes to the same value. Possibly `android-versionCode` has to be a whole number, while `ios-CFBundleVersion` can have decimal points?

Comment: Good point.  In my case, the ios bundle has a decimal but the android does not.  So ios has a build of 2.58, but android has a build of 258. I keep the two in sync so it is at least possible to tell the two devices use basically the same build.

Comment: version is with decimals, its what you call your version name "1.0.0" build number must be incremental integer, so ="1" eventually after some builds you notice that build number does not equal version name, they don't have to be a match, and they won't match eventually since build number is unique number that cannot repeat ( after being uploaded to the App store / google play console)